# Azure Agent config setup error WinHttp Error: ERROR_WINHTTP_TIMEOUT

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

Getting "WinHttp Error: ERROR_WINHTTP_TIMEOUT" error when config.cmd is run in corporate network over VPN. This worked fine last week, but this week it stopped working.
Error log is here

```html
2020-04-22 22:33:37Z ERR  VisualStudioServices] Attempt 4 of GET request to https://dev.azure.com/XYZ/_apis/connectionData?connectOptions=1&lastChangeId=143163415&lastChangeId64=143163415 failed (WinHttp Error: ERROR_WINHTTP_TIMEOUT). The maximum number of attempts has been reached.
[2020-04-22 22:33:37Z INFO VisualStudioServices] Finished operation Location.GetConnectionData
[2020-04-22 22:33:37Z INFO LocationServer] Catch exception during connect. 4 attempt left.
[2020-04-22 22:33:37Z ERR  LocationServer] System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
 ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException (80072EE2, 12002): Error 12002 calling WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_REQUEST_ERROR, 'The operation timed out'.
   at System.Threading.Tasks.RendezvousAwaitable`1.GetResult()
   at System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.StartRequestAsync(WinHttpRequestState state)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssHttpRetryMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage message, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Object userState, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.SendAsync[T](HttpRequestMessage message, Object userState, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Location.Client.LocationHttpClient.GetConnectionDataAsync(ConnectOptions connectOptions, Int64 lastChangeId, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Object userState)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.GetConnectionDataAsync(ConnectOptions connectOptions, Int32 lastChangeId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.ConnectAsync(ConnectOptions connectOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.LocationServer.ConnectAsync(VssConnection jobConnection)
[20
```

The GET URL https://dev.azure.com/XYZ/_apis/connectionData?connectOptions=1&lastChangeId=143163415&lastChangeId64=143163415 is accessible and when run on powershell window, Response code is 200

```html
StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : {"authenticatedUser":{"id":"aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa","descriptor":"System:PublicAccess
                    ;aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa","providerDisplayName":"Anonymous","customDisplayName":"Anony
                    mo...
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    Pragma: no-cache
                    X-TFS-ProcessId: 2efc9e7a-2854-44d7-ada0-44a58e152504
                    Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
                    ActivityId: 4779c83e-93f6-4107-82fb-ca02c50d4d...
Forms             : {}
Headers           : {[Pragma, no-cache], [X-TFS-ProcessId, 2efc9e7a-2854-44d7-ada0-44a58e152504],
                    [Strict-Transport-Security, max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains], [ActivityId,
                    4779c83e-93f6-4107-82fb-ca02c50d4d78]...}
Images            : {}
InputFields       : {}
Links             : {}
ParsedHtml        : mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass
RawContentLength  : 368893
```

Tried to set the proxy, but the same issue occurring. Any recommendations are welcome

Comment: How about this issue? Have you tried to execute following: `./config.cmd --proxyurl https://127.0.0.1:8888 --proxyusername “myuser” --proxypassword “mypass”` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/proxy?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows and have you add `https：// {organization_name} .vstmr.visualstudio.com` to firewall? https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/10047

Comment: Is this url " https://{organization_name}.vstmr.visualstudio.com/_apis/connectiondata" same as
https://dev.azure.com/{organization_name}/_apis/connectiondata ?
We are adding the dev.azure.com to the firewall

Comment: Proxy resolution suggested above did not work, we tried it

Comment: Did you try this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/certificate?view=azure-devops-2020